# Data not saving in JSON file from dynamic textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am saving data in a JSON file from HTML dynamic text boxes. Data tables are used. When I'm entering data from first page of data tables then data is going in JSON file but when I'm trying to save data from the second page of the data table then it saves only the second page of data. Data on first page will be blank.

Below is my code:

```js
var j = 0;
var opBal = new Array();
$('.txt_opBal').each(function() {
  var strid;
  strid = $(this).attr('id');
  strid = strid.slice(9);
  strid = strid - 1;
  opBal[strid] = $(this).val();
  j++;
});
```

Comment: You need to retain the array, here you are creating new instance of an array